# Change style of client-side Taxonomy picker from Sharepoint server

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm working on control Taxonomy from SP server. After setting up and getting data from SP server (other employee working on it) but now I have to change its style so it'll be consistent to other controls of the system.

This control is got from SP as follows http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/client-side-taxonomy-picker-for-sharepoint-app/

But as you can see in the last result we have is its default style (in image)

[image]

So my question is how to change the style of the textbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with adding style for these classes

```css
.ms-taxonomy .ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor .ms-taxonomy-writeableregion {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 height: 38px;
 line-height: 1.3;
 border: 1px solid #c4c7cc;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #323232;
 width: 100%;
 transition: border-color 0.25s ease;
 font-size: 12px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```